# Can you console.log inside our config/environment.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there any possible to console the value from `.env` file to our `config/environment.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The value will be printed out to the terminal when you run `npm start` or `ember test` or `ember serve` not to the browser console as `config/environment.js` is evaluated during the building of your app.

Comment: @Mikelemuel just add your `console.log('environment:', ENV)` before the `return ENV` statement at the end of the file.